# How to list only my articles in the reference section

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies, bibtex

With BiB(La)TeX, I am trying to produce a document like this [Web page](https://kdf.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekekule/citace.php).  That is,

1. A list of my articles, which I want BiB(La)TeX to print based on my input to the LaTeX source for the next part, which is
2. A list of articles by other people, which is given in the source as a list of BiB(La)TeX keys and then converted into the format similar to how they would appear in a citation list; each article is preceded by articles of mine that it cites, which I manually input in the source also as a list of BiBTeX keys.

In particular, I want the system to keep track of my articles that I `\cite` in the second section, but not other people's, and put it in the first section.  I have the following "non-working" example, which in the first section lists *all* articles cited in the second section:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{bibentry}
\title{list of citation response}
\author{John DOe}
\begin{document}
\renewcommand{\refname}{List of Cited Literature Items}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{bib}
\nobibliography{bib}
\section*{In Recent articles}
\begin{description}
\item[Citing \cite{myarticle}]
\bibentry{myadvisorsarticle}
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

(This seems like an FAQ or a very trivial task for people who are familiar with BiBLaTeX, but I don't understand the entirety of BiBLaTeX manual.  I apologize for a possible duplication.)

Comment: Your document uses classical BibTeX-based bibliography/citations and not `biblatex`, so I have removed the tag. (`biblatex` is incompatible with the classical BibTeX setup.) You may also want to edit the body of your answer to remove the "(La)" to avoid confusion.

Comment: @moewe I'm sorry for the confusion, but if what I want can be achieved by BiBLaTeX, then I will ditch BiBTeX.

Answer (score 1):

You could use one of these approaches (don't require overleaf)

https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/Questions/Creating_multiple_bibliographies_in_the_same_document#Bibliographies_for_different_categories

to create two categories of reference: one for your own papers and one for everything else.

Then, you can print the bibliography for your own papers in the normal way.

To print the bibliography for all the other papers, because you want to add the extra information about how they cite you, you can't -- as already pointed out -- just use the usual bibliography command.

Instead, you could cite them all manually with \fullcite:
`\cite{me1} \cite{me2} \textbf{in} \fullcite{g1}`

One disadvantage of this approach is that it won't "catch" if you \cite someone in the text, but forget to include them in the manual list.
As a workaround, you could create a second category, call it, say, manualcite, and write a wrapper around fullcite to add papers to that category. Then, at the end, you could have a final bibliography which would "catch" anything that hadn't been added to either category (as a check; you could remove this line once you were happy everything was in place)

Another problem here is that bibtex assigns numbers to all the cited references, not just yours. But maybe it will give you some ideas to work with.

```
\begin{filecontents}{shortbib.bib}
@misc{me1,
author={me},
title={my first paper},
howpublished={online}
}
@misc{me2,
author={me},
title={my second paper}
}
@misc{me3,
author={me},
title={my third paper}
}
@misc{jd1,
author={john doe},
title={another paper}
}
@misc{jd2,
author={jane doe},
title={a different paper}
}
@misc{jd3,
author={juliet doe},
title={yet another paper}
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=ext-numeric, articlein=false]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{shortbib.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyCategory{me}
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{manualcite}
\newcommand{\citeme}[1]{\cite{#1}\addtocategory{me}{#1}}
\newcommand{\longcite}[1]{\addtocategory{manualcite}{#1}\fullcite{#1}}

\begin{document}
% some text, with citations
I wrote a paper \citeme{me1}. And another \citeme{me2}. Some people
\cite{jd1} \cite{jd2} liked it. I wrote a third paper \citeme{me3} and
that was used by \cite{jd3}.

\hrule

\underline{Bibliography}
%my papers
 \printbibliography[category={me}, title={My papers}]
 % other papers

 \underline{Papers citing me}
 
\begin{itemize}
  \item  \citeme{me1} \citeme{me2}, \textbf{in} \longcite{jd1}
  \item \citeme{me1} \citeme{me3}, \textbf{in} \longcite{jd2}
\end{itemize}

% the check line -- did we forget anybody? 
\printbibliography[notcategory={me}, notcategory={manualcite},  title={Other papers}]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice solution. In my P.S. at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708143/245790 I'll relate your solution to the conceptual blueprint I described. Unfortunately, at the moment the last drawing is missing, which will hopefully be resolved soon.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some analysis and a blueprint towards your solution:

- What you have as standard-LaTeX
- Generalized data model
- What you want as non-standard-LaTeX
- Implementation study with Access
- Concluding remarks
- P.S.: How [MairAw's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708162/245790) follows this conceptual blueprint

I will assume you generate .pdf from LaTeX here, though, with some restrictions, you can also generate html from .tex . However, the key problem is neither touched nor solved by this detail.

#### What you have as standard-LaTeX

If you'd translate your code to biblatex, that's what you have right away:

- a database of literature
- `\cite` features
- printing that bibliography

The result will be the upper entries from the webpage you cited:

[image: bib_own]

#### Generalized data model

Now, let's have a look at the generalized datamodel, which underlies both data entry and generation of bibliography:

- you have a class for the cited documents
- which holds relevant attributes
- may provide functions()
- may be indexed by some (id) (which is already towards implementation, but it's easier to assign indices for instances=entries of this class in your mind)

[image: dm1]

For example, if you'd use a citation management program like `Zotero`, you can enter all kind of literature:

[image: zotero]

And if you select, e.g. for authors, it provides some `exportBiblatex()` functionality, triggered by menu actions, creating e.g. `extract.bib`; with manual creation you yourself do provide this function:

```
@online{wikipediaCarlWilhelmNaegeli2019,
    title = {Carl Wilhelm von Nägeli},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carl_Wilhelm_von_N%C3%A4geli},
    abstract = {Biographische Beschreibung des Botanikers},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    date = {2019-06-22},
}

@online{wikipediaOligodynamie2020,
    title = {Oligodynamie},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oligodynamie},
    abstract = {Der Begriff der Oligodynamie geht auf den Schweizer Botaniker Carl Wilhelm von Nägeli zurück und beschreibt eine schädigende Wirkung von Metall-Kationen (positiv elektrisch geladene Metallionen) auf lebende Zellen.},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    date = {2020-01-04},
}

@online{Wiki2023,
    title = {Digital Engineering},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital_Engineering},
    abstract = {Teildisziplinen unter Digital Engineering},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    date = {2023},
}

@online{Wiki,
    title = {Attention (machine learning) - Wikipedia},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Attention_(machine_learning)},
    abstract = {In artificial neural networks, attention is a technique that is meant to mimic cognitive attention. This effect enhances some parts of the input data while diminishing other parts—the motivation being that the network should devote more focus to the important parts of the data, even though they may be a small portion of an image or sentence. Learning which part of the data is more important than another depends on the context, and this is trained by gradient descent.

Attention-like mechanisms were introduced in the 1990s under names like multiplicative modules, sigma pi units[1], and hyper-networks.[2] Its flexibility comes from its role as "soft weights" that can change during runtime, in contrast to standard weights that must remain fixed at runtime. Uses of attention include memory in fast weight controllers,[3] neural Turing machines, reasoning tasks in differentiable neural computers,[4] language processing in transformers, and {LSTMs}, and multi-sensory data processing (sound, images, video, and text) in perceivers. [5][6][7][8]},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Attention (machine learning) - Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\P9NL9HA6\\Attention_(machine_learning).html:text/html},
}

@online{Wikia,
    title = {Word embedding - Wikipedia},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_embedding},
    abstract = {In natural language processing ({NLP}), a word embedding is a representation of a word. The embedding is used in text analysis. Typically, the representation is a real-valued vector that encodes the meaning of the word in such a way that words that are closer in the vector space are expected to be similar in meaning.[1] Word embeddings can be obtained using language modeling and feature learning techniques, where words or phrases from the vocabulary are mapped to vectors of real numbers.

Methods to generate this mapping include neural networks,[2] dimensionality reduction on the word co-occurrence matrix,[3][4][5] probabilistic models,[6] explainable knowledge base method,[7] and explicit representation in terms of the context in which words appear.[8]

Word and phrase embeddings, when used as the underlying input representation, have been shown to boost the performance in {NLP} tasks such as syntactic parsing[9] and sentiment analysis.[10]},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Word embedding - Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\WB4GBEUI\\Word_embedding.html:text/html},
}

@online{Wikib,
    title = {Transformer (machine learning model) - Wikipedia},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer_(machine_learning_model)},
    abstract = {A transformer is a deep learning model. It is distinguished by its adoption of self-attention, differentially weighting the significance of each part of the input (which includes the recursive output) data. It is used primarily in the fields of natural language processing ({NLP})[1] and computer vision ({CV}).[2]

Like recurrent neural networks ({RNNs}), transformers are designed to process sequential input data, such as natural language, with applications towards tasks such as translation and text summarization. However, unlike {RNNs}, transformers process the entire input all at once. The attention mechanism provides context for any position in the input sequence. For example, if the input data is a natural language sentence, the transformer does not have to process one word at a time. This allows for more parallelization than {RNNs} and therefore reduces training times.[1]

Transformers were introduced in 2017 by a team at Google Brain[1] and are increasingly becoming the model of choice for {NLP} problems,[3] replacing {RNN} models such as long short-term memory ({LSTM}).[4] Compared to {RNN} models, transformers are more amenable to parallelization, allowing training on larger datasets. This led to the development of pretrained systems such as {BERT} (Bidirectional Encoder Representations from Transformers) and the original {GPT} (generative pre-trained transformer), which were trained with large language datasets, such as the Wikipedia Corpus and Common Crawl, and can be fine-tuned for specific tasks.[5][6]},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Transformer (machine learning model) - Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\STVSNRG6\\Transformer_(machine_learning_model).html:text/html},
}

@online{Wikic,
    title = {Generative pre-trained transformer - Wikipedia},
    url = {https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_pre-trained_transformer},
    abstract = {Generative pre-trained transformers ({GPT}) are a type of large language model ({LLM})[1][2][3] and a prominent framework for generative artificial intelligence.[4][5] The first {GPT} was introduced in 2018 by the American artificial intelligence ({AI}) company {OpenAI}.[6] {GPT} models are artificial neural networks that are based on the transformer architecture, pre-trained on large data sets of unlabelled text, and able to generate novel human-like content.[2][3] As of 2023, most {LLMs} have these characteristics[7] and are sometimes referred to broadly as {GPTs}.[8]

{OpenAI} has released very influential {GPT} foundation models that have been sequentially numbered, to comprise its "{GPT}-n" series.[9] Each of these was significantly more capable than the previous, due to increased size (number of trainable parameters) and training. The most recent of these, {GPT}-4, was released in March 2023. Such models have been the basis for their more task-specific {GPT} systems, including models fine-tuned for instruction following—which in turn power the {ChatGPT} chatbot service.[1]

The term "{GPT}" is also used in the names and descriptions of such models developed by others. For example, other {GPT} foundation models include a series of models created by {EleutherAI},[10] and recently seven models created by Cerebras.[11] Also, companies in different industries have developed task-specific {GPTs} in their respective fields, such as Salesforce's "{EinsteinGPT}" (for {CRM})[12] and Bloomberg's "{BloombergGPT}" (for finance).[13]},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Generative pre-trained transformer - Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\WS6HLCT9\\Generative_pre-trained_transformer.html:text/html},
}

@online{Wikid,
    title = {Literaturverzeichnis – Wikipedia},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literaturverzeichnis},
    abstract = {Ein Literaturverzeichnis ist eine unselbstständige Zusammenstellung von Literaturhinweisen in alphabetischer oder systematischer Form und damit eine spezielle Bibliografie. Es steht meist am Ende wissenschaftlicher Qualifizierungsarbeiten wie Diplom-, Magister-, Bachelor- und Master-, Staatsexamens- oder Doktorarbeiten sowie eines Aufsatzes in einer Fachzeitschrift und in Sachbüchern als Hilfsmittel für weitergehende Studien oder als Teil der Quellenangaben.

Bei den Quellenangaben wird manchmal unterschieden zwischen Zitaten aus Büchern und Zeitschriften oder weiteren Medien.},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Literaturverzeichnis – Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\ILEH9G3G\\Literaturverzeichnis.html:text/html},
}

@online{Wikie,
    title = {Wissenschaftliche Arbeit – Wikipedia},
    url = {https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wissenschaftliche_Arbeit},
    abstract = {Eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit ist ein systematisch gegliederter Text, in dem ein oder mehrere Wissenschaftler das Ergebnis ihrer eigenständigen Forschung darstellen. Wissenschaftliche Arbeiten entstehen im Allgemeinen an Hochschulen oder anderen, auch privaten, Forschungseinrichtungen und werden von Studenten, Doktoranden, Professoren oder anderen Forschern verfasst. Dies ist jedoch kein zwingendes Merkmal. Vor wissenschaftlichen Konferenzen oder bei Sonderausgaben einer wissenschaftlichen Zeitschrift wird in einem call for papers zum Einreichen wissenschaftlicher Arbeiten aufgefordert.

Wissenschaftliches Arbeiten zielt auf die Schaffung neuen Wissens und eine wissenschaftliche Arbeit im Sinne dieses Lemmas ist eines von mehreren Formaten, in denen Ergebnisse wissenschaftlichen Arbeitens zur weiterführenden Forschung und Lehre dargestellt werden können. Andere Formate wären z. B. Forschungskolloquien oder Vorträge auf einer wissenschaftlichen Konferenz.},
    author = {Wikipedia},
    urldate = {2023-06-15},
    file = {Wissenschaftliche Arbeit – Wikipedia:C\:\\Users\\indernet\\Zotero\\storage\\A582ZELI\\Wissenschaftliche_Arbeit.html:text/html},
}
```

But now, you need a different functionality, which is not provided out-of-the-box, as far as I know.

#### What you want as non-standard-LaTeX

[image: bib_cross]

The cross-referencing part is something new, which you probably need to implement yourself one way or the other. The beauty of the following datamodels lies in that:

- it shows easily, where you want to go
- it's open to implementation,
- e.g. even with its object-orientation, you can implement in non-object-implementing languages.

So, to generate aboves entries you'd need to be able to do some kind of self-reference within your literature database:

[image: dm2]

I.e. to provide multiCiters you need to store and work with this kind of relation, with data integrity:

[image: dm3]

For practical reasons, though the left and right classes have at least the same attributes, it may be easier to provide them twice: as a `citers-class`, and as an `ownDoc-class`, related to each other in a `many-to-many` relationship via a `multiRef-class`.

The `multiRef-class` must provide a new function `katedraExport()` :

- performs a query (if the class is implemeted as a database/table)
- generates LaTeX code, which is no big deal when you access the attributes, which renders as:

[image: owns]

`Zotero` can't do it, `Biblatex` can't do it right away, so you need to spend some effort here.

#### Implementation study with Access

Now that the target datamodel and its functionality is clear, at least a bit more, let's turn to implementation.

There are many ways to do it, like:

- using `.bib` files, created manually or with `Zotero` etc. and some scripting
- replacing `.bib`/`Zotero` by a database and let the queries generate the LaTeX code
- and many more

So, let's have a look how this could be done with Microsofts `Access`. Let's translate the datamodel concept into Access implementation:

- a `class` is a `table`
- a `class instance` (object) is a `row` in said table
- a `relation` amongst classes is mapped via a `new table`

Structure and content of `t_docs`:
[image: docs struct]
[image: docs content]

Structure and content of `t_multiRef`, which is just a table of index-pairs, *THE key information, you have to enter manually once*:
[image: mr struct]
[image: mr data]

Finally we need to specify the `relationship` between the tables:
[image: relation]

Now, here something important happens:

- this program can relate a table to itself:
- it just kind of copies the table
- however, queries fail, the way we need
- SO in this approach you'd need to define two tables for the documents,
- `t_citers` (not done here) and `t_ownDoc` (not done here), see above
- then you can fine-tune queries (Abfragen) the way you need and turn the values returned into LaTeX strings you need and save them to a file

#### Concluding remarks

I hope I could show and convince you that what you want isn't provided ad hoc by Latex, neither biblatex nor bibtex, as far as I know.

I showed you, how your objective output could be expressed as a generic datamodel.

There are many ways to implement that, e.g. by:

- scripting, including perl, latex3, python
- relational databases, like Access, mySQL etc.
- citation managers, like `Zotero`, PLUS some of the above
- there may or may not exist such an advanced citation manager already

The Access example I started will provide the code generators needed through a set of queries, ONCE two tables with identical structure are provided for the literature. The queries implement the `functions()` indicated in the datamodels.

So this answer is a kind of generalized blueprint, which can be implemented by concrete code in a huge number of ways.

#### P.S.: How [MairAw's solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/708162/245790) follows this conceptual blueprint

First let's recall that a self-referenced class

[image: dm2-recalled]

can always be expressed as a many-to-many relationship:
[image: dm3-recalled]

Using the latter it's possible to related the different parts of MairAw's solution to this conceptual blueprint:

[image: solution]
As you can see:

- there are some global definitions needed
- citers and ownDoc are simply parts within the same `shortbib.bib`
- the `multiRef` class is realized as the `citation key`
- where its `katedraExport()` function is realized by manual coding
- where own papers simply use the `\printbibliography()` from standard-latex